# How to get the gift message value in Magento2.1.7?

Tags: magento2, giftmessage

How to get the `gift message` value in `Magento2.1.7`?

I am getting the gift message value as `$getgiftMessage = $item->giftMessage();`

But I am not able to get the value.

**Any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: Are you trying to fetch it from quote?

Comment: I am fetching it from order.

Comment: I think you will get only gift message id from there.

Answer (score 4):

You can get Gift message for order item using below code.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\GiftMessage\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface $orderItemGiftRepo
) {
    $this->orderItemGiftRepo = $orderItemGiftRepo;
}

public function getGiftMessage($orderId, $orderItemId)
{ 
    $giftMessage = $this->orderItemGiftRepo->get($orderId, $orderItemId);
    $giftMessage->getMessage(); // This will give you message
}
```

I hope it will helpful :)

Comment: I want to call gift message in phtml file.

Comment: Then you can put this code in block file and call getGiftMessage() function

Comment: You can use \Magento\GiftMessage\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface to get the gift message for the whole order

Answer (score 0):

In case if you need get message value on checkout/cart page you can use `\Magento\GiftMessage\Model\MessageFactory`

For example in your block:

```
protected $_messageFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\GiftMessage\Model\MessageFactory $messageFactory
)
{
    $this->_messageFactory = $messageFactory;
}

public function getGiftMessage()
{
    $giftMessage = $this->messageFactory->create();
    $item = $this->getItem(); 
    if ($item->getGiftMessageId()) {
        $giftMessage->load($item->getGiftMessageId());
        return $giftMessage->getMessage();
    }

    return '';
}
```